# FunctionDomain doesn't work with If

Tags: functions

When I call `FunctionDomain` for function defined by a formula with `If`, for example

```
f[x_]:=If[x<0, x, x^3]
```

I get

> FunctionDomain::nmet: Unable to find the domain with the available methods.>>

What should I do to get a domain of that defined function?

Is any different solution than checking domains of that functions apart?

Comment: I think you may want to use `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x < 0}}, x^3]` instead of using `If`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you were using `FunctionDomain`, but running the following example gets your error:

```
f[x_] := If[x < 0, x, x^3]
FunctionDomain[f[x], x, Reals]
(* FunctionDomain::nmet: Unable to find the domain with the available methods. >> *)
```

Changing `If` to `Piecewise` works though.

```
f2[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x < 0}}, x^3] 
FunctionDomain[f2[x], x, Reals]
(* True *)
```

If you take a look under the "Background" of `If` [in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html?q=If), that should clear it up a little as to why `If` fails but `Piecewise` works.

> `If` is a procedural programming structure whose evaluation branch is
>   determined by the truth value of a specified condition.
>   ...
>   Mathematical functions that evaluate depending on the values of their
>   arguments include `Boole` and `Piecewise`.

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for, thank you for quick response